# Batch if statement was, unexpected at this time

Tags: batch-file

This is my code:

```
@echo off 
echo Menu
echo.
echo 1. Create
echo 2. Define
set /p %PROGRAM%=:
if %PROGRAM%==1 goto cre
if %PROGRAM%==2 goto def
```

Even if I use enableDelayedExpansion it still says goto was not excpected at this time.

Answer (score 1):

rather you need:

```
@echo off 
echo Menu
echo.
echo 1. Create
echo 2. Define
set /p PROGRAM=:
if %PROGRAM%==1 goto cre
if %PROGRAM%==2 goto def
```